# arp-scan: command not found after install

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation

I installed `arp-scan` using `apt-get install arp-scan`.

I have a succesful install message with the newest version (1.9.5-1).
However, when I try to type in the command in bash I get the following error:

```
bash: arp-scan: command not found
```

It does not appear to be in `/usr/bin` despite the successful installation. How could I fix this issue?

System: Debian 10

Comment: What about `sudo arp-scan --localnet` ?

Comment: Paste the output of `dpkg -L arp-scan`

Answer (score 2):

The package installs `/usr/sbin/arp-scan`.  Note *sbin* and not `bin`.

If `/usr/sbin/` isn't on your path then you can run it will the full path name.  If it is on you can try

```
hash -r arp-scan
```

or logout and login again to get it to be detected.

Comment: Thanks, you're right it wasn't on my path. I added /usr/sbin to my root user path using export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin and now command works, along with standard utilities like reboot and shutdown.